# The proper installation of PixiJS in Angular 6

Tags: angular, pixi.js

I got a problem with a proper installation of PixiJS in the Angular 6. I tried to:

```
npm install pixi.js
```

and than:

```
npm install --save @types/pixi.js
```

also modified my path in script array:

```
 "scripts": [
         "node_modules/pixi.js/dist/pixi.min.js"
    ],
```

but when add the script from [tutorial](https://github.com/kittykatattack/learningPixi):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let type = "WebGL"
    if(!PIXI.utils.isWebGLSupported()){
      type = "canvas"
    }

    PIXI.utils.sayHello(type)
  </script>
```

to my index.html just to check if Pixi is connected, I still got an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: PIXI is not defined
```

What should I change? Could you help me with the solution?

Comment: Try changing it to "../node_modules/pixi.js/dist/pixi.min.js"

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: Instead of using this in HTML script, why don't you call it from a component where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to the top of your component's *.ts file, right after any @imports you may have:

```
declare var PIXI:any;
```

That will allow you to access it from your Typescript file.

If you can't access it from your  code, then try importing it like this:

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';
```